# JavsScript: Reduce array of dictionary into Array

Tags: javascript

I get this response from REST API.

```
"items": [
            {
                "name": "one"
            },
            {
                "name": "two"
            }
        ]
```

I want to reduce it to array `["one", "two"]`. Can someone please tell me how?

Comment: yes you do it by using map

Answer (score 3):

```js
const res = {
  items: [{
      name: 'one'
    },
    {
      name: 'two'
    }
  ]
};

console.log(res.items.map(res => res.name));
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

using **map**

```
var items = [
  {
    name: "one",
  },
  {
    name: "two",
  },
];

console.log(items.map((item) => item.name));
```